# How to select distinct and non-null values from a dataframe column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can  select distinct and non-null values from a dataframe column in py-spark.

Comment: what did u try?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out...following is the command where i am selecting all the unique UserID's from column and excluding empty rows:

```
df.select('UserID').distinct().where(col("userid").isNotNull())
```

Still i believe there can possibly be better alternative.